# Find all groups of order 121 up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find all groups of order $121$ up to isomorphism.

if i'm right, all such groups are abelian groups, since this is $p^2$ for $p$ = $11$ and $11$ is prime.

there's only one, isn't there? isn't it just $\mathbb{Z}_{121} $ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{11} \times \mathbb{Z}_{11}$ ?

Comment: No, there's more than one.  Note $\Bbb Z/121 \Bbb Z$ is cyclic, while the highest order in $(\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z)^2$ is 11

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: Can you show that $\Bbb{Z}_{121}$ and  $\Bbb{Z}_{11} \times \Bbb{Z}_{11}$ are not isomorphic?

Comment: $Sammy 
wait, they're NOT isomorphic? Well no, I guess I couldn't...

Comment: @Ryan: Tim has given you a hint.

Comment: how does one determine whether or not two groups are isomorphic, then?

Comment: Well, properties of isomorphism of two groups can help you to prove that they are NOT isomorphic. Some of these properties are : the group will have same order, they will have same number of elements of a fixed order; they will have same number of subgroups etc.